# Dynamic select with data-attribute doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have an empty `select` element with dynamically added `option` elements. The `option` elements have a `attribute` called `data-municipality`.

I'm using this variable in a function, but it is as though the function just gets "undefined" instead of the actual variable value.

Here's my function, that sets the variable and prints it to the console:

```
  $( "#fromMunicipality" ).change(function() {
    fromMunicipalityCode = $("#fromMunicipality option:selected").data("municipality");
    console.log(fromMunicipalityCode);
  });
```

And here's the function I'm using the variable `fromMunicipalityCode` in:

```
$('#fromAddress').dawaautocomplete({
  adgangsadresserOnly: true,
  params: {
    kommunekode: fromMunicipalityCode
  },
  select: function(event, adresse) {
  }
});
```

When I run the function above, `fromMunicipality` is undefined, even though the attribute changes in the console, or at least it doesn't use the value in the function.

What could be the issue here?

Thanks!

Comment: If the change event isn't fired and you just declare globally `fromMunicipalityCode`, it will be undefined. Maybe you just need to set this variable on page load. So when declaring it on global scope: `var fromMunicipalityCode = $("#fromMunicipality option:selected").data("municipality");`. Now on change event, you'd need to reinitialize plugin with new value. BUT your question is missing a MCVE, your issue and your expected behaviour would be more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `dawaautocomplete` inside change event:

```
$( "#fromMunicipality" ).change(function() {
    fromMunicipalityCode = $("#fromMunicipality option:selected").data("municipality");
    console.log(fromMunicipalityCode);
    $('#fromAddress').dawaautocomplete({
      adgangsadresserOnly: true,
      params: {
         kommunekode: fromMunicipalityCode
      },
      select: function(event, adresse) {
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: I'd trigger change event on page load to get the default value

Comment: @A.Wolff, how would I go about that? I would need to call the dawaautocomplete function twice, right — one on page load, and one on change?

Comment: @hoegenhaug `$( "#fromMunicipality").change(function() {...}).change();`. Now, i don't know this plugin `dawaautocomplete`. Check DOC, it could handle dynamic property initialization

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$( "#fromMunicipality").change(function() {
     fromMunicipalityCode = $("#fromMunicipality option:selected").attr("data-municipality");
    console.log(fromMunicipalityCode);
    $('#fromAddress').dawaautocomplete({
          adgangsadresserOnly: true,
         params: {
            kommunekode: fromMunicipalityCode
         },
        select: function(event, adresse) {
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: How is that different than Jayesh's answer posted **12 minutes** ago???  EDIT: ok, you use `attr()` but `data()` in this case would work just fine

Comment: he had used data instead of attr.
you said, you were adding options dynamically, than why not pass the data-municipality value directly to option's value.
it would become more easy to fetch value.

Comment: Ya, you are mixing both other answer, that could be it but here i guess it isn't. BTW, i think you should trigger change event on page load: `$( "#fromMunicipality").change(function() {...}).change();`

Answer (score 0):

That's how I thought it should work, also. But yesterday I found it was necessary to code like this:

```
fromMunicipalityCode = $("#fromMunicipality option:selected").attr("data-municipality");
```

See if that works for you.